Install cert as admin for special user via windows admin center
I try to install a cert, a website uses to auth the visit. That means I have to install it local and manually by logging into the user acc and install it under "CurrentUser\My". If I install it for the whole machine "LocalMachine\My" it will be ignored when I try to access the website (seems Chrome don't check these certs).
Manually that works. But I want to make life easier using windows admin center. The problem is that I log into the machine with an admin account. When I navigate to cert, there is no option to import a cert for a special (different) user account. Is there a way to install it (maybe via powershell) for a special user without knowing his password? I mean - I'm the admin of that machine, I should be able to do that.
Unfortunately it seems that I cant't explain that in short words to let google know what I try to do...
